# Can top.sls be changed using any salt commands/modules

Tags: salt-stack

or it can only be edited manually using text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no internal functions to modify your top.sls

The top file is yaml, so you could dynamically create a data structure in python or your favorite programming language and output that structure to your top.sls.

There is also the master tops system, which allows you to dynamically create your top data.

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/master_tops/index.html